# package statement not working

Tags: java, compilation

```
package com;

class Account {

    public double balance;

    public Account(double initBalance) {
       balance = initBalance;
    }
}
```

Account.class file is generated but it in same folder. File sub folder named 'com' is not created.
Actually I tried to compile directly . Now I can see its totally wrong to compile a java file folder without specifying root directory . ( -d . )

Comment: how is it generated? are you using any IDE?

Comment: more information is needed.

Comment: no i am not using any IDE just editplus.

Comment: then you have to create `com` folder manually and put Account.java in it, then compile

Comment: E:\data\fold\java1mods\Module2\excercise4\BankPrj in this folder Account.java is saved.AFter compiling this file i expect a com folder is automaticaly created and the account.class is stored init.

Comment: i suggest you use an IDE (e.g. Eclipse)...you shouldn't even bother approaching development/deployment this way

Comment: ok then whats use of package statement? @NikolayKuznetsov

Comment: possible duplicate of [java packages: cannot find symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527941/java-packages-cannot-find-symbol)

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov:  That's...not true.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov.. Compiler only do what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are compiling your code from command line, then you can use the following command to automatically create the folder corresponding to your packages: -

```
javac -d . Account.java
```

This will create a folder `com` in the current folder, where your `Account.java` is placed, and move the class file automatically to that folder.

Note that, packages are there for your `class files`. You can place your `.java` file anywhere. But in addition, your corresponding `.class` file should be inside a folder corresponding to your `package` in your `.java` file.

For e.g, see the below directory structure: -

```
root --+ Account.java 
       |
       +-- com --Account.class  (com is the package folder)
```

So, the fully qualified name of your `Account` class becomes - `com.Account`.

Then in order for your `Account` class to be found by other class, set the classpath till the `com` folder ( **Note**: - Don't include the `com` folder in classpath).

Comment: +1 @Rohit you are simply awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, package is nothing, it's a folder (non-technically). So be sure, your `.java` is created inside `com` folder/package. Also, `com` is not a part of any folder/package. If you are working on some IDE like Netbeans, then **right click** on package and **New** then **java class**.

**Update**

If you are not using any IDE, then check your **class path**. If `E:\data\fold\java1mods\Module2\excercise4\BankPrj\` is your `class path`. Then, create `com` folder and create your `.java` file inside same directory i.e. `com`.

Comment: Moving `Account.java` inside the `com` directory will not solve the problem.