# java packages: cannot find symbol (2)

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

my question is almost the same as this one : [java packages: cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527941/java-packages-cannot-find-symbol)

Suppose you have two classes A and B, declared respectively in the files A.java and B.java, with B used in the class A. Then the command line "javac A.java" will work perfectly. But somehow if you add both A and B in the same package (adding the line : "package toto;" at the begining of each file), then "javac A.java" will give the error that the symbol "B" cannnot be found.

The solution given above ([java packages: cannot find symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527941/java-packages-cannot-find-symbol)) was to call the compilation line : "javac A.java B.java" and this works. I would like to know if there is a solution to make it work, but compiling the java files one at a time. (I use java 7).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apart from putting them in package `toto`, you have to move them in a `toto` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move A.java and B.java into toto folder.
See: [Managing Source and Class Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)

Comment: This works just fine, thanks you. Apparently I have to wait now to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`A` uses `B` and `B` does not use `A`, right? This is what I guess from your question. Based on this you should first compile `B` and then `A`.

```
javac B.java //generates B.class
javac -cp . A.java 
//It is important to add current-folder (location of B.class) in classpath
```

Above doens't uses `package` declaration, for working with `package`, I think the solution posted in above link should work fine:

Suppose your dir structure is :

```
main -|
     toto -|
           A.java, B.java
```

So inside main directory:

```
$main: javac -sourcepath ./toto -d ./toto B.java
$main: javac cp ./toto -sourcepath ./toto -d ./toto A.java
```

Above uses `toto` for both `source` and `bin` folder.

Comment: I think it does not matter, what If A uses B and B uses A anyway ?